# how to make PHP echo data as it in table

Tags: php, echo

**Current Code:**

```
  // Display flight details
            echo "<h2>Flight Details</h2>";
            echo "Aircraft Name: $aircraft_name<br>";
            echo "Arrival Country: $arrival_country<br>";
            echo "Scheduled Arrival Time: $scheduled_arrival<br>";
            echo "Actual Arrival Time: $arrival_actual<br>";
            echo "Departure Country: $departure_country<br>";
            echo "Scheduled Departure Time: $scheduled_departure<br>";
            echo "Actual Departure Time: $departure_actual<br>";
            echo "Flight Status: $flight_status<br>";

        } else {
            echo "Flight not found or API error.";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Expecting format:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6EB1.png)

I'm looking for table format

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong? It seems pretty straightforward to make the output that you want with some basic HTML and CSS.

Comment: As @droopsnoot said this is basic HTML. StackOverflow is the place to come to if you're stuck and can't find a way out of a problem, but isn't a substitute to doing your homework. People providing answers to this kind of questions are only encouraging laziness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://3v4l.org/o3ISN (Click on the eye icon on right side of the Output section to see the HTML preview)

```
$data = [
    "Aircraft Name" => "N/A", // Use variable: $aircraft_name
    "Arrival Country: " => "Chennai", // Use variable: $arrival_country
    "Scheduled Arrival Time" => "2023-09-04", // Use variable: $scheduled_arrival
    "Actual Arrival Time" => "2023-09-04", // Use variable: $arrival_actual
    "Departure Country" => "Dubai", // Use variable: $departure_country
    "Scheduled Departure Time" => "2023-09-04", // Use variable: $scheduled_departure
    "Actual Departure Time" => "2023-09-04", // Use variable: $departure_actual
    "Flight Status" => "Arrived", // Use variable: $flight_status
];

echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tbody>";

// First row, 2 columns: 1st column value is "blank" and 2nd column value is "Flight Details" (depends where you want to keep)
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td>Flight Details</td>";
echo "</tr>";

// Iterate the data using foreach instead
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style= \"background-color:#114882; color:#fff;\">{$key} :</td>";
    echo "<td>{$value}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```